# Initial value problem using sin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find a solution to the initial value problem:
> $y'(t)+sin(t)y =g(t) , y(0) =9$ ,
> that is continuous on the interval [$0,2π$] where:
>
> [image]

---

I don't understand what I am doing wrong in this problem. It is an online homework and when I enter my two answers only the first one is correct while the second one is not. My answers are:

$y= 1+8e^{(cos(t)-1)}$ if $0<t<π$

and

$y=-1+8e^{(cos(t)-1)}+8e^{(cos(t)+1)}$ if $π<t<2π$

But the second answer is incorrect and I don't know why. Does anyone see what could be wrong? All help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hints

Is your function $y(t)$ $\textbf{continuous}$ on the interval $[0,2\pi]$?
Also note that the boundary condition $y(0)=9$ needs to be only satisfied by $y(t)$ defined on the interval $0\leq t\leq \pi$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Is your $y(t)$ continuous at $\pi$? That is, is $\lim_{t\rightarrow \pi^{-}}y(t)=\lim_{t\rightarrow \pi^{+}}y(t)$ satisfied?